# What is a static member function? Can we use a static function to initialize a parent functor?

Tags: c++, static-members

I ran into a situation where I have two classes, class A is a templated class with a template function F, and B is A's child, which instantiate F. Can I just use a static function to do that?

```
template<typename F>
class A{
public:
    class A(const F& f):_f{f}{}
    F _f;
};

class B: public A<std::function<double(const double&)>>{
    public:
        B():A<std::function<double(const double&)>{fb}{};

        static double fb(const double& x){return x;}
};
```

Can I do this? What is the difference between this way, and the way where I initiate the B function using some function defined outside the class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a static member function?

A function inside a class not bound to class instance.

> Can we use a static function to initialize a parent functor?

Yes.

> Can I just use a static function to do that?

Yes.

> Can I do this?

No, your code has syntax errors. There should be no `class` before `A` constructor, and `B():A<.....` line is missing a `>`. After fixing errors, you can compile the code.

> What is the difference between this way, and the way where I initiate the B function using some function defined outside the class?

The difference is exactly in that - one is initialized with a function defined outside the class, the other with a function defined inside the class.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! You solved my problem. I tried with a simple case where I succeeded in initializing a functor using a static function.